# Error while runing static content deploy

Tags: magento2.3

We are in the process of migrating our magento from 2.2.2 CE version to 2.3.6 CE version. After migrating while running content deploy getting below errors:

> #0 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
> #1 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(62): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
> #2 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
> #3 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(189): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('css/images/fanc...', Array)
> #4 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(133): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
> #5 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(102): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
> #6 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service{closure}()
> #7 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(187): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
> #8 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/State/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure), Array)
> #9 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure))
> #10 /var/www/posicweb/posicgit/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(358): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deploy(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array)

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/ generated/

Comment: DO NOT chmod 777!!!!!!

Comment: Totally agree with @PhilippSander 90% of suggesstions are either redeploy or use chmod with 777. Take care. Also it looks like you didn't added whole error message, only a stack of a request.
Moreover I would suggest checking var/log/ and var/reports :)